# subprocess.run returns ValueError: embedded null byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

**Explanation**

I try to start a .sh file inside a python3 script with subprocess.run
data is the content of a RFID Card with 16 3-digit numbers. I write a Filename to the card-content which is then converted to ASCII format. When reading the card it is converted back to the Filename.

**Code**

```
# Check if authenticated
if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
    data = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Read(8)
    # delete blank spaces
    res = [0 if item == 255 else item for item in data]
    # data is an ASCII code from an RFID card, 
    foldername = "".join(chr(x) for x in res)
    videofile = (str(foldername)+".sh")
    # check if videofile has the correct value/name
    print(videodatei)
    videostart = ("/home/pi/Documents/" +videodatei)
    # check if the complete folder has the correct value
    print(videostart)
    #it is working and returns the exact same value as the working code below
    #this one is working: subprocess.run(['/home/pi/Documents/jonah_aktuell.sh'])
```

**Exception**

```
subprocess.run([videostart])
```

returns the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "MyRead3.py", line 70, in
>
> subprocess.run([videostart])   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 472, in run
> with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
> restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1453, in _execute_child
> restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn) ValueError: embedded null byte

**What I have tried**

As you can see "videostart" and it's content don't contain a NULL. I also checked, that the variable is a string and made sure with the string() function.

I googled tons of "solutions", but all of the problems contained NULLs somewhere in the variable content, mine doesn't.

I also tried subprocess.call() with the same result.

Comment: Provide the trace of the error there will be a line in the trace which would be throwing this error. Add that error trace in the question

Comment: Also print the output of `foldername` and `videofile` when condition on `res` is `item == 255`.

Comment: argv syscall arguments are C strings. C strings aren't allowed to contain NULs.

Comment: So `chr(0)` is a value you can never include in a filename passed on a command-line argument in UNIX

Comment: Also, what do you expect to happen when `item == 47` (a forward slash, which is a directory separator in filenames)?

Comment: ...you're saying that you checked and your data contains no NULs, but you're  *showing us code that creates those NULs*, so it'd be better if you _demonstrated_ that the problem occurs with no NULs, instead of just asserting it.

Comment: ...for such an demonstration, [edit] your code to assign a specific value to `data` for which the issue is known to take place; the goal for any [mre] is that someone else should be able to copy-and-paste your code with no changes whatsoever and see the problem themselves; if someone needs to provide their own value of `data`, that's not "no changes whatsoever"..

Comment: @think-maths thanks for your comment. I added the trace. your second comment may lead to the answer. The ASCII code contains 16 numbers and the last ones are 255. I tried to get rid of them by turning them into NULLs before converting ASCII to Text. I assume that these NULLS may be converted to spaces, which I can't see when printing the converted text. I'll try to fill all 16 numbers with a value to test if that's the problem.

Comment: Terminals don't necessarily print NULs _at all_ -- not even as spaces. They're treated as filler, "do-nothing"/noop characters for traditional ANSI-compliant terminals. If you want to show what's in a string in a visually-unambiguous way, `print(repr(yourstring))`; using `repr` is _critical_.

Comment: ...what I would suggest here is base64-encoding or hex-encoding your strings before trying to make filenames of them; that way your names are guaranteed to be human-readable, and _also_ to contain no NUL literals.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for your reply. I thought these NULs would be converted into "nothing" when converting it to text. When I add the ".sh" there are no spaces between the data and the .sh, so I thought it worked like I planned it. I'll test it without 255 content. Also thanks for pointing out that someone else can't see the problem without all of the information, I'll edit that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy aaahhh. repr shows my misinterpretation, NULs are there. Thanks a lot. Next question is how do I get rid of them (or better get rid of the 255 values).

Comment: `replace('\x00', '')` is your friend, if you don't need the data to be preserved. Though as mentioned before, the approach I would take in the real world is hex, or base64, or base32, or similar encoding -- Python includes a lot of those as options out-of-the-box; the [`binascii` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) is a pretty good place to start.

Comment: ...what you _really_ don't want to happen is for a barcode to contain, say, data that encodes to `../../../../../etc/passwd`. Using an encoding that takes `.`s and `/`s out of the set of characters that can be created eliminates that headache along with all the others.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks a lot, It's working after replacing the NULs. So after all the problem was the wrong aproach to a problem I thought I already solved, since I thought I deleted the NULs. I'll try to embed your other suggestion too. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

- `chr(0)` is a NUL byte.
- UNIX syscalls have their arguments passed as C strings.
- C strings are NUL-terminated -- meaning, they're considered to end at the first NUL byte.

Thus, you cannot pass `chr(0)` as part of a command-line argument on UNIX, so `res = [0 if item == 255 else item for item in data]` ensures that `foldername = "".join(chr(x) for x in res)` will generate a value that cannot be passed in an argument vector if any value contains either 0 or 255.